# ActiveRecord. Is a transaction recommended here. How can I ensure all records are saved

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have the following.

```
files.each do |file_path|
   filename = file_path_to_file_name(file_path)
   feature = Feature.new
   feature.name = filename_to_name(filename)
   feature.filename = filename
   feature.suite_id = suite.id
   feature.save!
end
```

I want to make sure every feature gets saved, but if an exception is thrown I don't want to just stop. I don't want to just fail silently and move on as well, which is why I'm using `!` with `save`.

First off: Is this a case where I should be using a transaction (as in the following)?:

```
found_tests.each do |file_path|
   Feature.transaction do
      filename = file_path_to_file_name(file_path)
      feature = Feature.new
      feature.name = filename_to_name(filename)
      feature.filename = filename
      feature.suite_id = suite.id
      feature.save!
   end
end
```

Second, what are good ways to ensure everything gets saved? What risks are there when I'm regularly working on the order of less than 10,000 things being saved each time this particular script runs.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a validation, whatever you use `save` or `save!`, data won't persist. You would usually use `.transaction` when you are doing multiple updates, and say the last one fails, so you have to rollback previous updates as well. Your case is not such a case.
2. There are multiple ways to go around to make sure you've saved everything. Everytime you fail, you could keep a Redis queue or something, so you can investigate why some features didn't save and then attempt to fix and then save them again.

If you want to continue running your script, you'd want to rescue your exception and call `next` to move on to the next `file_path`

```
found_tests.each do |file_path|
  begin
    filename = file_path_to_file_name(file_path)
    feature = Feature.new
    feature.name = filename_to_name(filename)
    feature.filename = filename
    feature.suite_id = suite.id
    feature.save!
  rescue YourError => e
    puts e
    next
  end
end
```

Comment: Did I answer your question at all @david-west